# Semantic HTML markup for menu button (html5)

Tags: html, button, menu, semantics, markup

What would be the best way to markup a menu button? The idea is to have a button with a text like "add" to fold out and show the options you can add.

I like the `<menu>` html5 tag but the label attribute doesn't sit well with me as it would mean the text would only show if a piece of JS has been loaded that actually places the text (ok I could use css generated content, but that doesn't work in IE7/8).

I thought about a `<dl><dt>add</dt><dd>...</dd></dl>` construction but I don't think it covers the wanted semantics.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you mean. Perhaps if you could post a sample image of what you are talking about, we would be able to help more.

Answer (score 1):

You can place the actual element inside the label and still maintain a proper relationship between the two.

For example:

```
<label for="elementName"><element name="elementName" attribute="" attribute="">Element Label</element></label>
```

Similar to how one would markup radio buttons. I would attempt this sort of approach first, however, a simple unordered list might actually be what you are looking for, rather than a definition list, as with a definition list you need to specify a dt and a dd for each item.